# Add > in Visualforce Template Email Subject

Tags: formatting, visualforce-template

I need to add > to the subject of Visualforce email template. Like:

> Wayne Enterprise > Bruce Wayne

Directly adding > in the subject doesn't work. I have tried adding HTML code as shown below but they too don't work. Is there an alternative solution for this?

```
&gt;

&#62;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the one workaround for the same, use this :
{!RIGHT('>',2)}

Here is the out put :
[image]